# Using angular-translate on state parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I'm using `angular-translate` for localization and everything works fine except for translating data inside state parameters.

For example, I have a state like this:

```
.state('about', {
      url: "/about",
      isAbstract: true,
      template: '<ui-view/>',
      data: {
        title: 'About'
      }
    })
```

The title should be the translation key. I tried `title: $filter('translate')('ABOUT')` but it didn't work.

Any ideas on how I could do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use given syntax as below

```
.run(function($rootScope, $translate) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {
        if (toState.data.title) {
            $translate(toState.data.title).then(function(translation) {
                $rootScope.pageTitle = translation;
            },
            function() {
                $rootScope.pageTitle = 'About';
            });
        }
    });
})
```

Take look at example at [here](http://nscurious.com/2015/04/23/angularjs-ui-router-change-and-localize-page-title-for-each-state/)

Comment: It doesn't work writing this in the config file. It just prints it as we wrote (`{{ 'ABOUT' | translate }}`).

Comment: looks like that something else is wrong in your setup @superjim. maybe you could create a http://plnkr.co/ to reproduce the issue?